# Php print script not recognising javascript function:

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to implement a javascript function to change the style of a tr. However, it is not being recognised in my php file and is not being used in my javascript file. It is important to note that the button inclosed in the td is in a loop that loops through, counting the number of tables and then adding that number to their id. I have left out this code because it is working properly and is rather long. The error I am receiving from php storm is: 'Expression statement is not assigned or call.'

Php:

```
    <?php 
    print "<script type='text/javascript' src='mainJS.js'></script>";
    $amend_table = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `$table`");
    print "<table>";
    if ($table === 'TBL_Product') {
                    print "<h2>Product Table Selected:</h2>";
                    print "<tr>";
                    for ($count = 0; $count < count($TBL_Product); $count++) {
                        print "<th>".$TBL_Product[$count]."</th>";
                    }
                    print "</tr>";
                    foreach ($amend_table as $item) {
                        print "<tr id='table$tr_count'>";
                        $tr_count++;
                        for ($count = 0; $count < count($TBL_Product); $count++) {
                            $current_item = $item[$TBL_Product[$count]];
                            $current_ID = $item['ProductID'];
                            if (strlen($current_item) <= 60) {
                                print "<td>".$current_item."</td>";
                                if ($TBL_Product[$count] === 'Finish') {
                                    print "<td><button name='button$tr_count' onclick='edit_table($tr_count);'></button></td>";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                print "<th><span style='cursor: pointer' title='$current_item'>...</span></th>";
                            }
                        }
                        print "</tr>";
                    }
                }
    print "</table>";
    ?>
```

Javascript - (mainJS.js):

```
    function edit_table(tr_count) {
    let table = 'table'+tr_count;
    document.getElementById(table).style.border = 'orange 2px dashed';
    }
```

Comment: What are the `id`(s) of those `td`(s)? Are they `table1`, `table2`,... etc. ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The problem is that php won't recognise edit_table() as a function.

Comment: check browser console.

Comment: yes, that line is in a for loop and prints this: print "<tr id='table$tr_count'>";

Comment: your button not having any name

Comment: I have given each button a unique name and nothing changed.

Comment: @Kingwebbie001 Are you enclosing your `tr`(s) with the `table` tag?

Comment: I have included more code, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, my editing application, php storm was throwing a false error; the code works. Thanks for the help!